# Ошибка mysql "Unknown column 'subcategories_category' in 'on clause'"

Tags: mysql

Запрос выдает ошибку.

> Unknown column 'subcategories_category' in 'on clause'.

Помогите найти ошибку.

Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT categories.id as categories_id, 
       categories.category as categories_category,  
       subcategories.id as subcategories_id, 
       subcategories.subcategory as subcategories_subcategory, 
       subcategories.category as subcategories_category 
FROM subcategories 
LEFT JOIN categories ON subcategories_category = categories_id
```

Comment: Нельзя использовать алиас выходного поля в выражении связывания. Хотя бы потому, что на момент связывания таблиц выходного поля и его алиаса тупо не существует.

Comment: Я только учу php. Поэтому ничего не понял, что вы сказали((

Comment: PHP тут вообще не при чём. Ошибка в MySQL-запросе. PS. Я откорректирую Ваш вопрос, удалю лишнее - так станет понятнее.

Comment: Видите? Вы в выражении связывания `ON subcategories_category = categories_id` используете алиасы полей выходного набора (новые имена, которые присваиваются через `AS`). Это - нельзя (причина описана выше, если не поняли - читайте основы SQL). Вы должны использовать имена полей из таблиц-источников, т.е. `ON subcategories.category = categories.id`.

Comment: Дополнительно. Скорее всего Вы используете неверный порядок связывания, поменяйте местами таблицы `FROM categories LEFT JOIN subcategories`, либо (хуже) замените `LEFT JOIN` на `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: А как понять какой порядок связывания или какой JOIN использовать? Я честно говоря читал, но так и не понял.

Comment: *как понять какой порядок связывания или какой JOIN использовать?* Если из таблицы нужны только записи, имеющие соответствие во второй таблице - INNER JOIN. Если из первой таблицы нужны все записи (где нет соответствия во второй - подставить NULL), то LEFT JOIN. Если наоборот - RIGHT JOIN. Если нужны все записи из обеих таблиц - FULL JOIN (в MySQL - не поддерживается).

Comment: Мне нужны все записи. Я делаю меню с категориями и подкатегориями. А а поля, которые связываю это подкатегории. Их нужно вложить в меню второго уровня. Как то так.

Comment: *Мне нужны все записи.* Представьте, что в таблице есть подкатегория, которая не отнесена ни к какой категории. Должна ли эта запись возвращаться? если да - как Вы намерены её отображать? Только не говорите "у меня такого не может быть"... или покажите структуру таблиц, где это поддержано соответствующим внешним ключом. Вот в то, что нужны все записи из таблицы категорий - в это верю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS categories_id,
    c.category AS categories_category,
    sc.id AS subcategories_id, 
    sc.subcategory AS subcategories_subcategory,
    sc.category AS subcategories_category
FROM subcategories sc
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = sc.category
```

Comment: sc и c это сокращения названия таблиц? Прошу прощения, но я только обучаюсь.

Comment: Да, для удобства использования

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.